# how many Full-Screen Transitions for ipad app are allowed?

Tags: objective-c, ipad

I am developing an educational iPad app, Im finally done with the code and its ready to submit but I just found about the "Reduce Full-Screen Transitions" rule.

**"For iPad: Reduce Full-Screen Transitions
Closely associate visual transitions with the content that’s changing. Instead of swapping in a whole new screen when some embedded information changes, try to update only the areas of the UI that need it. As a general rule, transition individual views and objects, not the screen. In most cases, flipping the entire screen is not recommended.
When you perform fewer full-screen transitions, your iPad app has greater visual stability, which helps people keep track of where they are in their task. You can use UI elements such as split view and popover to lessen the need for full-screen transitions."**

The guidelines basically say that it's not recommended it doesn't say it prohibited.
So if the app is build based on the full-screen transitions since it's a training app with three section each have 4 full screen transitions. Do you think that I should recode the whole thing because it would be rejected? Or 4 full-screen transitions for 3 buttons is not too much?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

That reads like a UI guideline rather than a "we will reject your app if it doesn't conform".  Any chance of posting a link to the doc where it comes from?

If it makes sense in UI terms for your app to use a full screen transition, I don't think there will be a problem.

Comment: Yes, it's in their UI guidelines here http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UEBestPractices/UEBestPractices.html
well the document says it's not recommended for iPad apps, and my app is for iPad. 
 when I searched about the subject many people were rejected for this reason. So I was wondering if anyone knows if 4 screens in each of the 3 button is too much that they will reject it or not?

Comment: @Lames If it makes for the best UI experience for your application, I think it will be fine.